# How to check if a tkinter app has been opened before? (Tkinter python)

Tags: python, tkinter, startup

I'm making an app in tkinter that has a start up/welcome screen. How could I check if the app has been opened before, so that the next time the person opens the app/runs the script, they don't get the welcome screen anymore. Also, I'd like for a reset option that would trigger the welcome screen again. I know this is achievable, but I just don't know how. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could have the program create a text file for example upon first launch. Then use something like a `try/except` to check for the file and then add the desired behavior accordingly? Your `try` could check for the existence of the file and your  `except` could handle `FileNotFoundError` and create the file and then generate the welcome screen? Just a quick idea maybe?

Comment: is the program able to delete it as well?

Comment: yes, just look up file operations with Python

Comment: @SShiels I added a quick example for what I meant.

Comment: create a config file via `configparser` and can use that to update on open, and subsequently check for previous open etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quick idea as there are many ways you could get creative with this. I love `try` and `except` for this type of behavior. It is a great tool for something like this IMO. Hopefully this gives you an idea of what I meant.

*UPDATED to add suggestions from comments

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import tkinter as tk


# consider changing directory to avoid permission issues as stated in comments based on OS
file = Path("File.txt")

try:
    with open(file, "r"):  # try to open the file
        print("Not first Launch, No welcome screen")
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open(file, "x"):  # "x" will create the file as pointed out in comments
        print("First time launch, file was created, welcome screen activated")


def reset():
    try:
        os.remove(file) # remove the file if it is there
        print("Reset perfomed, file deleted")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Program already reset")

        
root = tk.Tk()

reset_button = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", command=reset)
reset_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you don't need `reader.close()` or `f.close()` because you're using a context manager, also if you don't write to the file you can either use `x` mode to open file and catch `FileFoundError` or just use `os.path.exists`? or sth along that

Comment: There is one problematic case; if the program doesn't have sufficient rights to write in the working directory. In that case it would be best to change directory to the user's home directory first; `os.environ["HOMEDRIVE"] + os.environ["HOMEPATH"]` on windows or `os.environ["HOME"]` on POSIX systems.

Comment: @Matiiss I updated it to include those ideas, thanks, I had not used the "x" before, I always used "a" in those situations.

Comment: @RolandSmith  good catch, I added the comment as an additional reminder.